# SQL: replace NULL with SPACE

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a fixed length flat file (separated by ','), but when a field has a null value, the record moves. Please see illustration below (incorrect Jenny and Roland records):

Source Table:

```
Name    Color  Balance Zip Code
------- ------ ------- --------
Melissa Orange $200.00 40240
Karl    Blue   $150.00 40884
Jenny   -null- -null-  45667
Roland  -null- $110.00 53366
Vincent Green  $285.00 45677
```

Output I want to get:

```
Correct_Ouput
----------------------------
Melissa,Orange,$200.00,40240
Karl   ,Blue  ,$150.00,40884
Jenny  ,      ,       ,45667
Roland ,      ,$110.00,53366
Vincent,Green ,$285.00,45677
```

Output I want to get:

```
Wrong_Output
----------------------------
Melissa,Orange,$200.00,40240
Karl   ,Blue  ,$150.00,40884
Jenny  ,,,45667
Roland ,,$110.00,53366
Vincent,Green ,$285.00,45677
```

I tried searching but I get the null to empty string result.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `COALESCE(column,' ')` function.

For some databases, you can use IFNULL or NVL. See [this web page](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **NVL** to replace the **NULL** value with required number of **spaces** to retain the format.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT 'Karl' NAME,
  2    NVL('Blue', '     ') color,
  3    NVL('$150.00','         ') balance,
  4    40884 zip_code
  5  FROM dual
  6  UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 'Jenny' name,
  8    NVL(NULL, '     ') color,
  9    NVL(NULL,'         ') balance,
 10    45667 zip_code
 11  FROM dual
 12  /

NAME  COLOR BALANCE     ZIP_CODE
----- ----- --------- ----------
Karl  Blue  $150.00        40884
Jenny                      45667

SQL>
```

You could also use **DECODE**.

For example,

`DECODE(column, NULL, '      ')`